# Creating a ZIP file programmatically

Tags: c#, sharpziplib, devforce

My application will be storing large amounts of cached data to local storage for performance and disconnected purposes.  I have tried to use SharpZipLib to compress the cache files that are created, but I'm having some difficulty.

I can get the file created, but it is invalid.  Windows' built-in zip system and 7-zip both indicate that the file is invalid.  When I attempt to open the file programmatically through SharpZipLib, I get the exception "Wrong Central Directory signature."  I think part of the problem is that I'm creating the zip file directly from a MemoryStream, so there is no "root" directory.  Not sure how to create one programmatically with SharpZipLib.

The EntityManager below is the IdeaBlade DevForce-generated "datacontext."  It can save its contents to a stream for purposes of serializing to disk for caching.

Here's my code:

```
private void SaveCacheFile(string FileName, EntityManager em)
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(FileName, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew, isf))
                {
                    MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream();
                    MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
                    Crc32 crc = new Crc32();
                    em.CacheStateManager.SaveCacheState(inStream, false, true);
                    inStream.Position = 0;

                    ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(outStream);
                    zipStream.IsStreamOwner = false;
                    zipStream.SetLevel(3);

                    ZipEntry newEntry = new ZipEntry(FileName);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[inStream.Length];
                    inStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    newEntry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    newEntry.Size = inStream.Length;
                    crc.Reset();
                    crc.Update(buffer);
                    newEntry.Crc = crc.Value;
                    zipStream.PutNextEntry(newEntry);
                    buffer = null;

                    outStream.Position = 0;
                    inStream.Position = 0;                   
                    StreamUtils.Copy(inStream, zipStream, new byte[4096]);
                    zipStream.CloseEntry();
                    zipStream.Finish();
                    zipStream.Close();
                    outStream.Position = 0;
                    StreamUtils.Copy(outStream, isfs, new byte[4096]);
                    outStream.Close();    

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a zip file straight from memory is not your problem.  SharpZipLib uses the parameter in the `ZipEntry` constructor to determine the path, and does not care if that path has subdirectories or not.

```
using (ZipOutputStream zipStreamOut = new ZipOutputStream(outputstream))
{
    zipStreamOut.PutNextEntry(new ZipEntry("arbitrary.ext"));
    zipstreamOut.Write(mybytearraydata, 0, mybytearraydata.Length);
    zipStreamOut.Finish();
    //Line below needed if outputstream is a MemoryStream and you are
    //passing it to a function expecting a stream.
    outputstream.Position = 0;

    //DoStuff.  Optional; Not necessary if e.g., outputstream is a FileStream.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove `outStream.Position = 0;` and it works.